# How do I get KLIPS or NETKEY on 11.10 server?

Tags: 11.10, ipsec, openswan

I'm attempting to run OpenSWAN on my Ubuntu11.10 server. [All I've done so far is install openswan from the package manager](http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html) and attempt to set up conf files. However, IPSec support seems to be broken, thus OpenSWAN can't do it's thing.

**Attempt to start IPSec**

```
$ sudo ipsec setup --start
ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec 2.6.28...
ipsec_setup: No KLIPS support found while requested, desperately falling back to netkey
ipsec_setup: Even NETKEY support is not there, aborting
```

**Verify IPSec**

```
$ sudo ipsec verify
Checking your system to see if IPsec got installed and started correctly:
Version check and ipsec on-path                                 [OK]
Linux Openswan U2.6.28/K(no kernel code presently loaded)
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [FAILED]
Checking that pluto is running                                  [FAILED]
  whack: Pluto is not running (no "/var/run/pluto/pluto.ctl")
Checking for 'ip' command                                       [OK]
Checking for 'iptables' command                                 [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]
```

**IPSec Version**

```
$ sudo ipsec version
Linux Openswan U2.6.28/K(no kernel code presently loaded)
See `ipsec --copyright' for copyright information.
```

**Linux build:**

```
$ uname -a  
Linux metabox 2.6.18-028stab092.1 #1 SMP Wed Jul 20 19:47:12 MSD 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I go about correcting this problem with IPSec? This is a hosted VPS, and I'd like to avoid a kernel rebuild if I can find some other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Without an archival ISO and archived packages I don't think this can be solved.  The extract of the Contents-amd64.gz from Natty repos tells me `grep 'linux-image-2.6.1' Contents-amd64` from 11.10 returns an empty set for that query. As far back as I can go is 2.6.38-8 as indicated by `grep 'linux-image-2.6.3' Contents-amd64 | sort -r`

With a kernel update to current it can be.  Will the OP please let me know if a kernel update to current is do-able.  It was indicated otherwise in chat.

Comment: Okay, not "can't be", but if you put the time in to it to solve it then you're spending more than you're making.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a kernel update as I don't want to shut down this server and go through any potential issues restarting it as this is a VPS host.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the needed module like so:

`sudo modprobe af_key`

Then add it to `/etc/modules`:

`af_key`